# NLS analysis in R with timeseries data to remove known effect

Tags: r, time-series, nls

I have a timeseries dataset collected by sensors. The data is crack displacement (`disp`) and temperature (`temp`). Thermal expansion is linear with temperature, so it causes a diurnal signature in my displacement data. I would like to remove the effect from temperature. I'm an engineer, not a statistician, so I am uncertain that I am doing it correctly.

I've used R's `nls` function to remove the known effect of temperature. I used a sin wave with 24-hour period. I also used a shift parameter (phi) in the function to shift the wave (because the `temp` sensor responds faster than the `disp` sensor which is mounted on concrete that takes awhile to heat and cool).

**My questions are:  Am I doing this correctly? Is there a better way?**

Note that I do not want to predict crack displacement, I want to remove effects of temperature and see the underlying 'unexplained' displacement.

I've developed a pseudo time series that somewhat mimics my data.

Here is my code (requires package `lubridate`):

````
# create 1 hour timeseries 1 week long
dat <- data.frame(TIMESTAMP = seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct('2020-03-01'), 
                                          to = as.POSIXct('2020-03-08'),
                                          by = '1 hour'))

# Add displacement data and temperature data.
# Use a sinusoidal pattern with random element
set.seed(1)
dat$disp <- sin(as.numeric(dat$TIMESTAMP)) + runif(n = nrow(dat), min = -0.2, max = 0.2)
dat$temp <- sin(as.numeric(dat$TIMESTAMP)) * runif(n = nrow(dat), min = 0, max = 5) + 20
plot(dat$TIMESTAMP, dat$disp)
plot(dat$TIMESTAMP, dat$temp)

# Add a trend to displacement - this is the unexplained displacement that I am looking for
dat$disp <- dat$disp + seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = nrow(dat))*rnorm(1)

# Equation for nls:
# D = b0 + b1*T + b2*sin(omega*t + phi)
    # D = predicted displacement
    # T = temperature
    # omega = angular frequency = 2*pi / 24
    # t = time of day (1...24)
    # phi = time shift between temperature and displacement
    # b0, b1, b2 are fitting parameters

# Provide starting parameters for nls()
b0 <- 1.0
b1 <- 1.0
b2 <- 1.0
phi <- 20

# create time of day (tod) series
library(lubridate)
dat$tod <- hour(dat$TIMESTAMP)

# model
fit <- nls(disp ~ (b0 + b1 * temp + b2 * sin(2 * pi * tod / 24 + phi)), 
           start = list(b0 = b0, b1 = b1, b2 = b2, phi = phi),
           data = dat)

# assign modeling results (residual and fitted points) to dat
dat$res <- resid(fit)
dat$fit <- fitted(fit)

# regression on residuals to get the slope
fit2 <- lm(dat$res ~ dat$TIMESTAMP)

# plot original data
plot(dat$TIMESTAMP, dat$disp)

# plot residuals (the 'unexplained' part of displacement)
points(dat$TIMESTAMP, dat$res, col = 'red')

# plot the fitted values (the 'thermally explained' part of displacement)
points(dat$TIMESTAMP, dat$fit, col = 'green')

# add slope line through the residuals (movement not caused by thermal effects)
abline(a = fit2$coefficients[1], b = fit2$coefficients[2])
```
````

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't look like a valid one, because you "assume the conclusion" by specifying the sin time dependency. You can try one of 2 options instead:

1. Use Generalized Additive Model with cyclical splines from mgcv package.
2. Get the displacement due to temperature expansion from physics theory (temperature at time with appropriate shift) * coefficient of thermal expansion for the relevant material (concrete?) and just subtract it from actual observation

If the time lag between the temp and disp censors is non-negligible, you need to account for it with a model like `disp_t = b0 + b1 * lag(temp_t, temp_disp_lag) + ...`. If this lag is unknown, then this is a really big problem and I am afraid there is no good solution.

Explanation:

The displacement linearly depends on temperature and on "something else":
`disp_t = b0 + b1 * temp_t + u_t`

You want to plot "something else" (displacement unexplained by temperature). If you somehow estimate b0 and b1, this is simply:

`u_t = disp_t - b0 - b1 * temp_t`

The effect that interests you is linear, so you don't need NLS. As a first idea you could try running a simple OLS:

```
m = lm(disp ~ temp, data = dat)
dat$dispOther = dat$disp - predict(m, newdata = dat)
```

However, the problem here is that u_t is autocorrelated and not iid (if it were iid, why would you want to plot it?) and even worse, it is correlated with time (that's why you want to plot it) and via time with temperature, so you have endogeneity and the OLS estimates are inconsistent. If you knew the functional form for the u_t dependency on time (`u_t = f(t) + e_t`, where e_t is stationary noise uncorrelated with temp_t and t), you could model and estimate b0, b1 and f parameters with an equation like this:

`disp_t = b0 + b1 * temp_t + f(t) + e_t`

If you assume that f(t) = sin wave with 24 hour period, you can estimate everything with nls like you did, but the result would be as good as this assumption. The assumption is likely wrong. Do you really know a priori that whatever process you are trying to measure with displacement sensors has exactly sinusoidal dependency on time besides the temperature dependency?

You can get a non-parametric estimate for the time dependency with `mgcv` package.

```
library(mgcv)
m = gam(disp ~ temp + s(t, bs="cp",...), data = dat)
dat$dispOther = dat$disp - coef(m)['(Intercept)'] - coef(m)['temp']
```

This would approximate the dependency of displacement on time with a smooth cyclical function (with a bit of magic). I don't remember right out of my head how to specify cyclical splines in mgcv, but you can check it [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/smooth.construct.ps.smooth.spec.html)

A completely different approach would be to avoid any statistical estimations at all and get the displacement change due to temperature from physics and some reference table for relevant materials. This could be trivial or impossible depending on your specific case.

Comment: Wow, thanks, great answer. I'll start digging through and see what I come up with and will mark as correct after.

Comment: You said "Your approach doesn't look like a valid one, because you 'assume the conclusion' by specifying the sin time dependency."  What if I'm super confident that outdoor temperature, measured long term, DOES display a diurnal sinusoidal pattern? Do I need to prove this again?

Comment: If you can reasonably assume that temp is reasonably represented as sin + noise, then it helps a lot. I just thought that this is unreasonable assumption, but you have the data and you know better. You can just fit Temp ~ hour, plot the residuals and see if sin is a reasonable approximation.

Comment: Actually, the biggest question is what do you expect to find in the unexplained displacement. If this is just some occasional spikes, possibly autocorrelated, but without deterministic diurnal pattern, then just do OLS `m = lm(disp ~ temp, data = dat)` and look at the residuals, there is no need for anything more complicated. If this is some diurnal pattern, then it is pretty hard to disentangle it from temp diurnal pattern and knowing that temp has a diurnal sin pattern, but unexplained displacement doesn't have a sin pattern helps a lot and you can proceed as you have suggested.

Comment: Awesome that you are still looking at this! I am also. The `dat$disp` (the crack-width data) is from cracks in a concrete dam (or in granite, in another of my projects). They display diurnal movement highly-correlated `dat$temp` (measured with the same sensor), which, engineering-wise, makes perfect sense. The unexplained displacement would be a movement in the dam or granite caused by other-than-temperature, which would be a permanent offset in `data$disp`. It is this permanent offset that I am trying to measure.

Comment: Another difficult part to this is that the crack widths display not only hourly temperature dependence, but seasonal temperature dependence. This is because of the massive nature of the structure. E.g., on a warm sunny winter day, the sensor temperature might by relatively high, as well as the first few inches of dam face, but the massive dam structure is still cold internally. One way I get around this in one of the projects is to use only temperature data collected at 4:00 am (reducing thermal effects on the sensor from direct sunlight).

Comment: ok, so the *actual* question is totally different!You are interested in long-term (scale in days-months) persistent changes in disp. Don't worry about intraday patterns, just take the average daily disp or your 4:00am as a clever hack. The actual problem is yearly seasonality (summer => higher temp => bigger disp doesn't mean cracks). You can measure the disp~temp dependence by regressing day on previous day changes in average daily disp on changes in average daily temp. Then plot daily observations for disp - b * temp, where b = coef from the last regression = empirical disp ~ temp dependence